# Remove sticky header when scrolled to the very bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [Auto-Hide Sticky Header](http://osvaldas.info/auto-hide-sticky-header) by Osvaldas Valutis. My JS file looks like this:

```
  $window.on( 'scroll', throttle( throttleTimeout, function()
  {
    dHeight         = $document.height();
    wHeight         = $window.height();
    wScrollCurrent  = $window.scrollTop();
    wScrollDiff     = wScrollBefore - wScrollCurrent;

    $element.toggleClass( elClassSlide, wScrollCurrent > elSlideOffset ); // toggles "slide" classname

    if( wScrollCurrent <= 0 ) // scrolled to the very top; element sticks to the top
      $element.removeClass( elClassHidden );

    else if( wScrollDiff > 0 && $element.hasClass( elClassHidden ) ) // scrolled up; element slides in
      $element.removeClass( elClassHidden );

    else if( wScrollDiff < 0 ) // scrolled down
    {
      if( wScrollCurrent + wHeight >= dHeight && $element.hasClass( elClassHidden ) ) // scrolled to the very bottom; element slides in
        $element.removeClass( elClassHidden );

      else // scrolled down; element slides out
        $element.addClass( elClassHidden );
    }

    wScrollBefore = wScrollCurrent;
  }));
```

Basically it adds and removes class `header-hidden`. I would like to change the script and show no navigation (i. e. add class `header-hidden`) when the page is scrolled to the very bottom. I tried to do the following, but it doesn't work.

```
    else if( wScrollDiff < 0 ) // scrolled down
      $element.addClass( elClassHidden );
```

Any idea how I can change the script?

Answer (score 1):

I have done something like this for my sidebar.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
      if(($(window).scrollTop() > 150) && ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $(document).height() - 400))
   { 
            $(".collpage").addClass('withfixed');
            $(".sidebar.three.columns").addClass('fixedfilters');

    }
    else
    {
     $(".collpage").removeClass('withfixed');
     $(".sidebar.three.columns").removeClass('fixedfilters');
   }

       })
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have any idea how I can change the code in my question?

Comment: Basically, you can use your own class header-hidden instead of my class fixedfilters. If you have added the fixed position in css with this class, then adding and removing this class should work. You have to add or remove class to the element which you want to make sticky. You can ignore the withfixed class lines.